# Leave one out using "cvpartition"

Tags: matlab, cross-validation

I am using cvpartition (in Matlab)to partition my data (10 times) and one out at each time for cross-validation. If one data at the first fold is out how we can make sure that the second time(next fold) the used data for the first round won't be used?Is this function prevents from using the same data for the second round of cross validation?Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Obviously it will be used again. Please understand the concept of cross-validation first. also looking at the [documentation of cvpartition](https://in.mathworks.com/help/stats/cvpartition.html?requestedDomain=in.mathworks.com) will help.

Comment: Thanks Vivek. I think there is a misunderstanding here I just want to know the probability of getting the same data(Index for test data ) which was used before on the next round of CV.

Comment: In Leave one out, the test data once used will never be used again in any other fold.